# Gtk, How to update GtkViewPort with GtkVBox

Tags: c, gtk

I am having one `GtkVbox` and I am adding it to `GtkViewPort`. View port is created from Glade file.

Now the problem is that my vbox keeps updating on every second (I keep adding widgets to vbox on every second) this vbox but my screen did not get updated as add widgets to my vbox.

I can't create new vbox every time as I need to keep previously added widgets in vbox.

How can I tell `GtkViewPort` to refresh list when I add new widgets to my GtkVBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you also call `gtk_widget_show()` on any widgets you add, or even `gtk_widget_show_all()` if what you add can have sub-widgets.

Comment: My mistake....actually i have not called `gtk_widget_show` on view port. Thanks for reply.